# Identifying the dual space of a Hilbert space using the Riesz representation theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I know the Riesz representation theorem for a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Then every continuous linear functional $f$ on $H$ is of the form $$f(u) =\langle u,v \rangle $$ where $u \in H$ and where $v$ is a uniquely determined element $v=v_f \in H$.

I am trying to understand how we can identify the  dual space $H^*$ of a Hilbert space $H$ using the Riesz representation theorem.

This is the proof.

I am told that from the theorem we can identify each $f \in H^*$ with a unique $v_f \in H$ for which $f =\langle \cdot , v_f \rangle$

Conversely each $v \in H$ induces a continuous linear functional $$f_v : u \to \langle u, v \rangle$$ where $u \in H$.

This means that there is a one to one between elements of $H$ and and those of $H^*$ so we can identify $H^*$ with $H$.

> My first question: In the theorem where is the dual space $H^*$
>   mentioned? I am not sure how we are told from the theorem that we can identify each $F \in H^*$.
>
> My second question:  What is the proof trying to say, what is it's general direction?
>
> My third question: What does  $f =\langle \cdot , v_f \rangle$ mean?

The problem is I can not see the connection betwen $H$ and $H^*$ in the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can restate the theorem as "for every $f \in H^*$ there exists a unique $v_f \in H$ such that $f(u)=\langle u,v_f \rangle$ for all $u \in H$."
2. Which proof? Are you asking about the proof of "we can identify $H^*$ with $H$" from the statement I just gave? The point is that each element of $H^*$ corresponds to an element of $H$ (by the statement above) while each element of $H$ corresponds to an element of $H^*$ (by bilinearity of the inner product and Cauchy-Schwarz).
3. $f=\langle \cdot,v_f \rangle$ means "$f(u)=\langle u,v_f \rangle$ for all $u$ in the domain of $f$".

Comment: I thought it was $f \in H$?

Comment: the problem is I can not see the connection between $H$ and $H^*$ in the theorem.

Comment: @Aljabra No, the function $f$ is defined on $H$, so it is in $H^*$. Did that answer your question or would you like more elaboration?

Comment: I see now, that is from the definition of a dual space. From wikipedia the dual space $H^*$ is the set of all linear functional on $H$.  From the Kreyszig book "introductory functional analysis with applications", the dual space $H^*$ is defined as the set of all bounded linear functional on $H$. Which definition is right? And we dont have a bounded linear functional do we?

Comment: @Aljabra There are distinct notions of "algebraic dual space" and "continuous dual space". The former consists of *all* linear functionals while the latter consists of just the bounded linear functionals. The one of interest in Hilbert space theory is the continuous dual space. Cauchy-Schwarz tells you that the functional $f(u)=\langle u,v \rangle$ is bounded. (As it happens, any linear functional on a complete normed linear space that you can explicitly write down is bounded, though one can "construct" unbounded linear functionals on complete normed linear spaces using the axiom of choice.)

Comment: How does Cauchy Schwarz tell us that $f(u)=\langle u, v \rangle$ is bounded?

Comment: @Aljabra $|f(u)| \leq \| v \| \| u \|$. So the "boundedness constant" is $\| v \|$.

Comment: what does $f_v : u \to \langle u , v \rangle$ come from and what does it mean?

Comment: @Aljabra Given a vector $v$ you have a function $f_v$ defined by $f_v(u)=\langle u,v \rangle$. What you have written is just different notation for this (usually the arrow is $\mapsto$, in LaTeX \mapsto).